# deploy custom docker image to helm values.yaml airflow on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, kubernetes-helm

Hi everyone I'm new in helm and kubernetes.

I'm using Airflow in my GCP kubernetes cluster, my objective is run my requirements.txt using a custom docker image

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.0

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I saw a lot of videos and examples with kind and the upgrade de image manualy with this command and targeting defaultAirflowRepository to airflow-custom

```
kind load docker-image airflow-custom:1.0.0 --name airflow-cluster
```

But I want include the image in each deploy of my `values.yaml` upgrade, can I do that?.

EDIT:

I'm using GKE and my docker image is a local Dockerfile, I want use this image in my deployment, it is necesary upload the image to docker hub or container registry repository to use it, or it is posible to use this image from my local repository in the values.yml?

Comment: You are using Google Kubernetes Engine, or you created Kubeadm cluster on Compute Engine VMs? What exactly you are trying to achieve? Your docker image would be somewhere locally or in some dockerhub?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I edited my question maybe this can gives you more details. I'm using GKE and my docker image is a local Dockerfile, I want use this image in my deployment, it is necesary upload the image to docker hub or container registry repository to use it, or it is posible to use this image from my local repository in the values.yml?

Comment: To understand fully, you are using GKE and you've installed KIND there? Regarding values.yaml you mention HELMs values.yaml? Recommended way is to use some kind of repository like dockerhub or GKE repository which is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app). Is there any specific requirement why you would like to use it from local?

Comment: Yes I searched from everywhere and it is not possible I wanted point my Dockerfile to the values.yaml of the helm airflow charts but it is not possible, is necessary push my image to a repository as Dockerhub or container registry of GCP, Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for the help, I searched for everywhere and it is not possible upload only my Dockerfile, is necessary up my image to a repository, no matters whish repository, in my case I used docker hub as you told me.

https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/halcolo/airflow-custom-providers

Other option for production is the repository of  container registry from GCP, after that I only need point my image with the respective version to the yml file

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you do that with werf !
https://werf.io/

Using werf you can upgrade your requirements.txt and trigger the new docker image upload and after the helm deploy with the new image